# Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX and blank cells

Tags: perl, parsing, xlsx

I am trying to parse through an XLSX file (getting the value for each cell, row by row,) using Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX.  Within my loop that goes through each row, I've tried pulling the values with this code:

```
$thisCell = $worksheet->get_cell($currentRow, $currentCol)->value();
```

and also with:

```
$thisCell = $worksheet->get_cell($currentRow, $currentCol)->unformatted();
```

However, the script always breaks if it encounters an empty cell.  The error method I get is "Can't call method [value|unformatted] on an undefined value..."

To try to anticipate or deal with the empty cells I have tried:

- putting an "or $thisCell = ''" after the above code
- wrapping the above code in a if clause like:

  ```
  if ($worksheet->get_cell($currentRow, $currentCol)->unformatted()) {
      $thisCell = $worksheet->get_cell($currentRow, $currentCol)->unformatted();
  else {
      $thisCell = "";
  }
  ```

I'm really stuck on this, and I'm sure it's something basic that I'm mucking up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($currentRow, $currentCol);

my $value = $cell ? $cell->value : undef;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank you for your assistance!